# SSRS tabbed report shifts right when clicked on Bookmark (Sharepoint mode) Only in IE

Tags: msbi

I have tabbed SSRS report created using bookmark functionality. When I click on any tab the report shifts left/right automatically and this happens only in Internet Explorer. The report works fine in Chrome.

FYI, the report is deployed in SharePoint integrated mode.

Kindly need your help.

Thanks in advance..

Regards,
Pravin K

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by left aligning all the objects on the report.